# What are the C# equivalents of the functions used in this PHP encryption code?

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I have been using the encryption class of codeigniter (PHP framework) for a while and need to convert these functions in PHP to C#. 
This is so that my C# application can decrypt the data on my website database and vise versa.

The problem is that I have recently started with C# so don't really know the function names that would do the same as PHP.

If I can convert these 3 functions, I'm sure I would be able to do their opposite 3 functions myself as they use near enough the same functions.

**Note:** *Please don't try to use these functions other than to play around - they are not strong cryptography (in fact, the method used could even be broken before the invention of computers).*

```
/**
 * XOR Encode
 *
 * Takes a plain-text string and key as input and generates an
 * encoded bit-string using XOR
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @return  string
 */
function _xor_encode($string, $key)
{
    $rand = '';
    while (strlen($rand) < 32)
    {
        $rand .= mt_rand(0, mt_getrandmax());
    }

    $rand = $this->hash($rand);

    $enc = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
    {           
        $enc .= substr($rand, ($i % strlen($rand)), 1).(substr($rand, ($i % strlen($rand)), 1) ^ substr($string, $i, 1));
    }

    return $this->_xor_merge($enc, $key);
}

    /**
 * XOR key + string Combiner
 *
 * Takes a string and key as input and computes the difference using XOR
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @return  string
 */
function _xor_merge($string, $key)
{
    $hash = $this->hash($key);
    $str = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
    {
        $str .= substr($string, $i, 1) ^ substr($hash, ($i % strlen($hash)), 1);
    }

    return $str;
}

/**
 * Adds permuted noise to the IV + encrypted data to protect
 * against Man-in-the-middle attacks on CBC mode ciphers
 * http://www.ciphersbyritter.com/GLOSSARY.HTM#IV
 *
 * Function description
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @return  string
 */
function _add_cipher_noise($data, $key)
{
    $keyhash = $this->hash($key);
    $keylen = strlen($keyhash);
    $str = '';

    for ($i = 0, $j = 0, $len = strlen($data); $i < $len; ++$i, ++$j)
    {
        if ($j >= $keylen)
        {
            $j = 0;
        }

        $str .= chr((ord($data[$i]) + ord($keyhash[$j])) % 256);
    }

    return $str;
}


/**
 * Hash encode a string
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string
 * @return  string
 */ 
function hash($str)
{
    return ($this->_hash_type == 'sha1') ? sha1($str) : md5($str);
}
```

Comment: Yikes! Are you implementing your own encryption algorithm?

Comment: And doing so by treating text as binary data? Double yikes!

Comment: @Aircule: yeah it gets to me too how people can't seem to figure that out.

Comment: @Thomas The php class uses mcrypt for encryption.

Comment: @arbme: Does PHP not have *standardised* encryption routines (AES etc)? They're always a better idea than rolling your own. Likewise if you've got text data which you want to encrypt, you should first convert it to binary data, then encrypt, and then if you need to represent the encrypted data as text use something like base64. Treating text as opaque binary data (e.g. using bitwise operations on it) is very *very* likely to lead to data being lost.

Comment: @John Skeet: Thanks for the reply. I think I will just make my own PHP class with Mcrypt but leave out those functions above if you think there is a chance on data loss. You just made alot things easier... Thanks again

Comment: @arbme: I just added some disclaimer to the question, so nobody reading this will have the idea to use these in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i'll give you small hint. all C-like constructs and operators go as is, other:

- strlen - `String.Length`
- substr - `String.Substring`
- . - `+`, .= - `+=`
- chr(c) - `(byte)c`
- ord(i) - `(char)i`

Comment: `ord(i) - (char)i` There are a couple things wrong with this. `ord` takes a string or a single character. Secondly, `char` in .net is a `Unicode 16-bit character` (2 bytes). `ord` on the other hand `Converts the first byte of a string to a value between 0 and 255` (1 byte).

Comment: @KellyElton good point, `ord` in PHP doesn't work with Unicode, to begin with. Indeed `char` in .net is 2-byte unsigned int, but in terms of value, UTF16 has the same int value as Latin1, UTF8 or any other standard encoding that uses 1 byte to encode chars with codepoints 0-127. Second point is that in the original question the author did `% 256` so my answer was a general direction for his task, not a general conversion guide.

Comment: @Andrey Sure. I've just seen this comparison a lot while looking up `ord` so I wanted to point that out so someone didn't blindly think they were equivalent.